# SparkR get distinct values from Dataframe fast

Tags: r, apache-spark, analytics, sparkr

I'm trying to get the distinct values from a SparkDataframe using below statement.

```
distVals <- collect(distinct(select(dataframeName, 'Column_name')))
```

To execute this statement, it takes around 30-40 minutes. Is there any better way to perform this?

Also there is not much time difference in collecting full dataframe and collecting distinct values. So why is it suggested not to collect entire dataset? Is it only because of the data size?

Since I have to get different kinds of filtered data, I'm looking for collecting the results faster.

Comment: In short `distinct` is expensive and `collect` in SparkR  is very slow. Otherwise there is not enough details to give you a better answer. What is the data, what are the resources, why do you need to `collect`...

Comment: I'm taking the data from **Oracle database** directly by establishing connection using jdbc. I'm collecting distinct values from this dataframe, so that I can use these values for future filtration with different dataframes.

Is it a good practice to extract data directly from a Relational database? Or do I need to use any separate ETL and store data in any other distributed file systems?

Comment: @Koushik I would use intermediate temporary tables to achieve this. Just strip down your data-set/frame to have columns only which are required; write them to a temporary table - You may choose to write a parquet file over writing a sql table in the spark. This is a very old school way to handle common operations on the spark r, but it works.